# erasing duplicate values in an ordered vector c++

Tags: c++, loops, vector, stl, iterator

I am trying to remove all duplicates in a vector of sorted strings. However, I keep on getting errors and I cannot really figure out why. I believe it has something to do with the vector resizing while also being used in a loop. Here is the code:

```
auto it = name.begin() + 1;
int count = 1; 

while(it != name.end())
{
    if (*it == *(it - 1))
    {
        count++;
        it++;
    }
    else if (*it != *(it - 1) && count > 1) {
        it = name.erase(it - count , it - 1);
        cout << *it << " occurs " << count << " times." << endl; 
        count == 1;
    }
}
```

The code checks to see if the previous element is duplicated and then removes it. It is important to know how many times the element occured as I would have to. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: `I keep on getting errors` please provide what errors you get.

Comment: Throw your code away and use [`std::unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique).

Comment: I nominate [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map), as it will give you the number of times each element occurred.

Comment: managed to fix it! I used std::map, where I would increment the value each time a certain key occured. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After you erased duplicated elements the current element does not have the preceding element.

```
else if (*it != *(it - 1) && count > 1) {
    it = name.erase(it - count , it - 1);
    cout << *it << " occurs " << count << " times." << endl; 
    count == 1;
}
```

Thus in the next iteration expressions `*it == *(it - 1)` and `*it != *(it - 1)` are invalid.

Moreover it can occur such a way that all elements before  `name.end()` will be equal each other. In this case nothing will be erased.

You can use standard algorithm `std::unique` declared in header `<algorithm>`.For example

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

//..

name.erase( std::unique( name.begin(), name.end() ), name.end() );
```

Answer (score 0):

> Any idea how to fix this?

Fun effort.  I believe I have identified 2 interesting possibilities.

Your loop started at the beginning of the vector 'name'.  This is fine. Now you need to find a mechanism to delay the vector::erase() of these duplicate elements. "vector::erase()" invalidates any iterator at or after that erase. It may be why vectors support operations at the back ... we can take advantage of this.

Found on the internet:  Iterator validity

- Iterators, pointers and references pointing to
   position (or first) and beyond are invalidated,
- All iterators, pointers and references to elements before position
  (or first) are **guaranteed** to keep referring to the same elements
  they were referring to before the call.

So, by working first at the back of the names vector, we can minimize pointer invalidations.

What I did, and suggest you try, is to add a second vector to hold the duplicate-element-iterators. I labeled mine dups, with the following typedef's

```
typedef std::vector<std::string>  Names; 
typedef Names::iterator           NamesIT; 
// --- 
typedef std::vector<NamesIT>      NamesItVec; 


vector<NamesItVec>  dups.
```

When you have identified all the duplicates, and have push_back()'d the names-iterators into dups, you can then spin through dups, at that time erasing the duplicate name-elements.

Note that when you erase from the back of a vector, the erase() has an easier time of its re-arrangement in memory.  (An effective 'second-use' of the earlier sorting effort.)

It looks like this:

```
std::cout << "\nremoving dups from vector name: back to front" << std::endl;

while (dups.size()) // as long as it has a iterator in it
{
   auto dupIT = dups.back(); // reference closest element to strVec.end()

   std::cout << "==> " << (*dupIT) << std::endl;  // debug info

   (void)names.erase(it);      // erase the single element

   dups.pop_back();             // remove the last element from dups
}
```

Hope this is not too much help.  Good luck.